# PHP using GET to pass variables

Tags: php, variables, get

how do i get rid of passed variable from my url without reloading the whole page? I don't want the variable to be there for more than one load of the website.

For example I have a website that has a main picture, there is a next button that goes to the next pic in the record. On the right there are a few pics randomly selected from the database. when you click on one of the randomized pics it is supposed to make it the main pic. The piclink passes the id variable to the url and the php checks for that and if it is set it goes to that id. otherwise it loads the next pic in the record. The problem is when I click on one of the pics on the right and the id is set, it stays set even when I click the next button. I need to clear the id from the url, how is this done?

Comment: You want to get rid of passed variables, use ajax

Comment: Please show your code, so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: A better solution is probably to have Javascript/AJAX handle image loading. This allows you to have a client-side script request each image from the server and forget about GET variables altogether.

Comment: I tried adding a second passed variable and then creating a file if that variable is set. Then reloading the page with just the id passed variable using the header function. Then the code would check for that file and the id being set and if both were true it would use that id, and delete the file. I figured this would make it not true on the next page load when the next button is hit since the file doesn't exist anymore and it would just go to the nect available record like it does in the beginning before clicking on any of the randomized pics. I don't know why but that didn't work.

Comment: How do I store something in session and what is session?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MxYwa5a2 Here is my code

Comment: I heard of Ajax I didn't really understand how to use it. See this is my father's site and I'm trying to fix it for him. In the future I will definitly use better coding techniques on my programs and sites but I don't want to do anything that will have to rewrite the whole site and it uses passed variables a lot. That's why I was looking for a way to do it with passed variables

Comment: Your code is pretty hard to read and understand., is there a place where we can see this online.?

Comment: It's plankingaround.com

Comment: If I get rid of the header function it works to load the random pic but breaks the next button. If I have the header function there it just loads the same image but changes the id in the url?

Comment: Where ever you are handling the next action. Put a redirect to the page without the id.
That should help you solve the problem without much change in code I guess

Comment: Nope that has the same effect as the redirect with the id?

Comment: Posted the answer, Check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the action attribute on the form for the next button to send the request to the page without id. What is happening now is that, since you are not setting the action attribute for the form,  the form is submitting to the page with the url taken from the browser's address bar.

add action attribute to your form in this line

```
$template = str_replace("[skipfunction]","<form name='form2' method='post' action=''><input type='hidden' name='voteval' value='6'>  <br><input type='hidden' name='voteid' value='$id'><button type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'><IMG src='images/formbutton.gif' width='40' height='40' />Skip to next </form> ",$template);
```

like this

```
<form name='form2' method='post' action='http://plankingaround.com/'>
```